# Can't open or rename SharePoint 2007 folders with plus sign in name

Tags: 2007, folder, sharepoint-library

We still have SharePoint 2007. I have users who have created/are creating folders with names starting with a plus sign (+). I can't see the folder when I'm accessing the SharePoint document library through the browser, but I can see the folder when using Windows Explorer. When I try to open the folder I get an error message saying:

> [Folder Path] refers to a location that is not available.

When I try to rename the folder I get an error message saying:

> Could not find this item. This is no longer located in [Parent Folder Path]. Verify the items location and try again.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to rename the folder so the user can access the files located within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to take care of the renaming issue. From our SP homepage I clicked Site Actions > Manage Content and Structure. Then navigated to the parent folder in the document library. The offending folder was listed. So I clicked the down arrow and Edit Properties to update the name. Voila, all fixed!

Answer (score 0):

There are some special charatere which SharePoint do not like at all. In your case you are using the `+` in your folder name which is again special characters. You cannot use these characters in your site name, site, groups, List, fodlers etc. Check the complete list here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231

While SharePoint allows you to [name a folder](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231) with a plus sign (+) but it bugs out when trying to open the file.

when You open a folder on SharePoint,it adds + sign URL which is real culprit here. Plus signs in a URL are a No-No.

http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2010/02/03/sharepoint-hates-plus-signs/

Comment: So could you provide a suggestion as how to fix this issue, rather than just confirm it?...

Comment: +1 to Andrey's comment. I reviewed the links you listed above and more before I posted my question, but found them to not help.

Comment: did you try to open the site in sharepoint designer? try it....how many folders you have? share the complete error.

Comment: Also try to create a new folder with + sign and see if you able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the folder in windows explorer.

Comment: See my original question. I state how that didn't work.